# Inherited class of gradle implementation dependency cannot be used in another module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my android project, I want to wrap a third party library, so I can prevent direct access to third party classes from app module.

In the wrap library, I add a dependency of third party library by `implementation`. `AppWorker` of wrap library extend `XWorker` of third party library, but when I call `AppWorker.doWork` in app module, there's a compile error: "cannot access XWorker".

If the `AppWorker` not extend `XWorker` but create a `XWorker` member for use, there will be no error, but this approach only works in some situation, because sometimes we must use inheritance, for example I need a customized `BroadcastReceiver` which extend a `BroadcastReceiver` of third party library.

If I use `api` instead of `implementation` in wrap library's dependencies, there will be no error too. But this will open access to third party classes when using wrap library in app module.

So, it seems I cannot inherit a class which is from implementation dependency and then use it in another module. Is this a bug of gralde? If not, why?

Below are sample code of three modules:

**thirdparty**

```
public class XWorker {
    public void doWorkX() {
    }
}
```

**wraplibrary**

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":thirdparty")
}

public class AppWorker extends XWorker {
    public void doWork() {
        // do some preparatory work
        super.doWorkX();
    }
}
```

**app**

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":wraplibrary")
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AppWorker worker = new AppWorker();
    worker.doWork();    // compile error: cannot access XWorker
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that it needs to expose the public methods of that class since they are public. Initially I thought if you wrap all the methods in a different method, so having doTheWork() call doWork. of the superclass. But I'm not sure that would work since still the method is public and you should be able to access the original doWork(). So what I'm thinking either API is used, since you need to access the public methods, or you don't inherit from the class, but create another class that acts as a proxy and has an instance of XWorker and calls its doWork().